# Search in particular category in wordpress

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

I am currently using the JSON API to get the data from wordpress

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

The plugin helps to retrieve the wordpress post data in JSON format

I notice that I can get the post within some category

```
http://www.test.com/?json=get_category_posts&id=9
```

And I can also search the post

```
http://www.test.com/?json=get_search_results&search=keywords
```

However, are there anyway to implement search within some category? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search post within category by two ways:

**First**

```
http://www.test.com/category/{category-slug}/?json=get_search_results&search={search-keyword}&cat=2
```

**Second**

```
http://www.test.com/?json=get_search_results&search={search-keyword}&cat=2
```

Second option actually redirect to first option, but it works.

Comment: Also , would you mind to teach me how to get the multi category? e.g. http://www.test.com/?json=get_category_posts&id=9 only get cat id 9, how about I would like to get all post from cat id 9 and cat id 10? Thanks

Comment: Right now its not possible by this plugin to search multiple category. is my given example work for you?

Comment: Yes. it works thanks. Then I just need to query for each category, I can still get my job done. Thanks